# Control number of digits with ifelse function

Tags: r

Im trying to control the number of digits for the object p. when I run the code it gets right "0.02", but it doesnt seem to be saved in "df". Why is this? How can it be fixed? Thanks!

```
p <- 0.023
 df <- if(p < 0.1 & p >0.001){
   print(p,digits=1)
 } else {
   p <- p
 }
 0.02
 df
 0.023
```

Comment: try using the `round(...)` function instead of the `print(...)` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print()` doesn't actually change the underlying object at all. Maybe you want `signif()`?

```
df <- if (p < 0.1 && p >0.001) {
   signif(p,digits=1)
} else {
   p
}
print(df)  ## 0.02
```

Notes:

- `round()` rounds to a specified number of digits, `signif()` to a specified number of *significant* digits (matching the `digits=` argument in `print()`)
- for `if` clauses, `&&` is usually preferred to `&`
- `a < b < c` doesn't work in R, but I might write the condition as `0.1 < p && p < 0.001` for slightly improved clarity

Comment: What's the reason behind `&&` for `if`? Didn't know that was a thing.

Comment: @Ben Bolker thanks for you answer! But it doesnt seem to work, I want it to round to 0.02...

Comment: `&&` is non-vectorized and does "short-circuiting" (e.g. in `A && B`, if `A` is FALSE then `B` won't be evaluated

Comment: oops, edited now.  (Left over from my experiments with `round()`)